# MailMerge error: Object doesn't support this property or method

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

Trying to do a mail merge in word from excel but getting a `Object doesn't support this property or method` error. Word opens up fine but none of the fields are populating. I have tried with and without the `connection` parameter.

Also, I thought the point of the `connection` parameter is so it won't prompt you for the table in excel for the merge?

```
wordFile = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "uyoic" & ".docx"
excelFile = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & ThisWorkbook.Name

Set appWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
appWord.Visible = True
appWord.Activate
Set wrdfile = appWord.Documents.Open(wordFile)
Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")

wrdfile.MailMerge.OpenDataSource Name:=excelFile ' Connection:="list"
wrdfile.Execute True
```

I have references VBA, Excel 16 Obj, Office 16 Obj, Outlook 16 Obj, Microsoft Scripting Runtime, Word 16 Obj, and VBA Extensibility 5.3 added. Am I missing one?

Comment: Side note - if you have a reference to the Word Object library, then you can change this from late binding to early binding: `Set appWord = New Word.Application`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need another reference because you're not using them.

When using CreateObject you're invoking objects with late bind.

Some suggestions:

1. Use Option Explicit at the top of your modules ([read this](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/option-explicit.html))
2. Try to name your variables with something easy to understand

Read code's comments and adjust it to fit your needs

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub MailMerge()

    Dim wordApplication As Object
    Dim wordFile As Object

    Dim wordFilePath As String
    Dim excelFilePath As String

    wordFilePath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "uyoic" & ".docx"
    excelFilePath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & ThisWorkbook.Name

    Set wordApplication = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    wordApplication.Visible = True
    wordApplication.Activate
    Set wordFile = wordApplication.Documents.Open(wordFilePath)
    'Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")

    ' This next line will ask for the source in WordApp (uncomment the SQLStatement and adjust it)
    wordFile.MailMerge.OpenDataSource Name:=excelFilePath ', SQLStatement:="SELECT *  FROM `Sheet1$`"  ' Connection:="list"
    wordFile.MailMerge.Execute True ' -> Execute method belongs to MailMerge

End Sub
```

Let me know if it works.

Comment: Thank you! I needed the `SQLStatemen` parameter which of course isn't really [explained](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.mailmerge.opendatasource) XD

Comment: hank you..It helped me a lot